# Favicon not showing in safari(iOS 12 13) but showing normally in Chrome(Android and PC)

Tags: iphone, vue.js, safari, favicon

My team are now developing a vue-cli based webapp that aims to works on Safari(iOS) and Chrome(android).
The favicon show normally on chrome but not showing in safari, or showing on some pages but not in some page.

I've figuring on this issue for like two weeks.
I tried to force refresh the favicon by `./favicon?v=2`, or use full url path or relative path, or use several different way to write favicon, but nothing works.
Sometimes the favicon just show for a second and a disappear.
Some pages say the safari iphone can be heavily cached but i can't find a good way to clean the cache.

I use vue-cli so the below link tag is written in public/index.html like below, and the favicon in public/favicon.ico.

```
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

after build, above code become code like

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.mysitesite.com/favicon.ico">
```

chrome android or chrome pc show normally but not safari ios

I also tried some code like below but don't work.

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.mysitesite.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.mysitesite.com/favicon.png?v=2" />
```

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

also, I tried generate favicon path by html-webpack-plugin but not show in safari.

apple-touch-icon shows when i bookmarked but favicon didn't show on the safari tab.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
```

Does anybody knows the solution or is this just a bug in safari?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You might want to run the favicon checker (https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker) to spot classic issues such as invalid paths. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.